# Modal popup dropdown list values bind twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have drop down list inside Partial view in asp.net MVC page. I am showing that partial view into the Modal Popup. I am binding values from data base to dropdown list

my problem is when i bind values to Dropdown List it binds twice?
can any one tell me why this happens

any help would be appreciated??

```
<select id="EntityType"></select>
```

```js
function Test() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/../MyFunction/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {   
            var options = $('#ddlcountry);                    
            $.each(data, function() {
                options.append($('<option/>').val(this.SHId).text(this.Name));
            });
        } // ajax callback
    });  // ajax call
}
```

This is the output I am getting

> value1
>   value2
>   value3
>   value1
>   value2
>   value3

Comment: hey man `debugger var options = $('#ddlcountry');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing options using `$('#ddlcountry').empty()` before adding new options.

```
$('#ddlcountry').empty();
var options = $('#ddlcountry');   
$.each(data, function() {
   options.append($('<option/>').val(this.SHId).text(this.Name));
});
```

Comment: @ KPL >> thanks buddy it works.. :) i really appriciate your help..
bye